# Recursive templates: compilation error under g++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, mingw

I am trying to use templates recursively to define (at compile-time) a d-tuple of doubles. The code below compiles fine with Visual Studio 2010, but g++ fails and complains that it "cannot call constructor 'point<1>::point' directly".

Could anyone please shed some light on what is going on here?

Many thanks, Jo

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

template <const int N>
class point
{

private:
  pair<double, point<N-1> > coordPointPair;

public:

  point()
  {
    coordPointPair.first = 0;
    coordPointPair.second.point<N-1>::point();
  }

};

template<>
class point<1>
{

private:
  double coord;

public:

  point()
  {
    coord= 0;
  }

};

int main()
{
  point<5> myPoint;

  return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What are you trying to do with:

```
coordPointPair.second.point<N-1>::point();
```

It looks like you want to explicitly call the `point` default constructor - which has already been called when the `pair` was constructed. You cannot call constructors directly (unless you use placement new, which wouldn't make sense in this scenario)

Just remove that line.

If you for some reason want to overwrite the already constructed `.second` by assigning to it from a temporary `point<N-1>` you can do so with `coordPointPair.second = point<N-1>();`.

If you, for a more complex case, want to pass arguments to a `point` constructor you can do this in the initializer list:

```
point(your_type your_arg) : 
    coordPointPair(
        pair<double, point<N-1> >(0.0, point<N-1>(your_arg_here))
    )
{
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution is to use the initialization list :

```
template <const int N>
class point
{

private:
  pair<double, point<N-1> > coordPointPair;

public:

  point() : coordPointPair( std::make_pair( 0.0, point<N-1>() ) )
  {
  }

};
```

What you implemented there is not c++ standard compliant. If you still want to initialize in the constructor, then do it like this :

```
coordPointPair.second = point<N-1>();
```

Comment: I would remove the `make_pair` call.  Just use the two argument `pair` constructor.

Comment: @aschepler Me too, but that example might be simplified in order to demonstrate the problem. The real constructor for point<N> might be more complex and even take arguments

Comment: Yes, you're right -- this is a simplified example; the real constructor does indeed take arguments.

Answer (score 2):

```
coordPointPair.second.point<N-1>::point();
```

This is illegal. You wanted to do this:

```
coordPointPair.second = point<N-1>();
```

By the way, it's not needed, because by the time this statement executes, the `coordPointPair.second` is already initialized with  `point<N-1>()`.

However, if there is any non-default constructor in `point<>`, then you can do this:

```
coordPointPair.second = point<N-1>(/*arg, ...*/); //pass the arguments
```

But again, it's better if you do this in the initialization-list!